# Giving text to fragments depending on args

Tags: android, android-fragments

The thing is that I want to give different text to the same fragment class for my pageviewer-supported application, depending on the argument's number. Basically, when you slide horizontally, the same fragment will show up but with different text. I'm in quite a strugle here, can anyone help me figure this out please? I'm sorry for my leak of knowledge and for asking newbie's question if this is the matter. Googled about this but was not succesful.

Comment: Post your existing code so others help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Fragment` class, you can add this and call `YourFragment.getInstance(/* custom text */)` to create the `Fragment` inside the `ViewPager`:

```
public static class YourFragment extends Fragment

    private String mText; // display this text in your fragment

    public static Fragment getInstance(String text) {
      Fragment f = new Fragment();
      Bundle args = new Bundle();
      args.putString("text", text);
      f.setArguments(args);
      return f;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
      super.onCreate(state);
      mText = getArguments().getString("text");
      // rest of your code
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, thanks! And how do I check what string text is given for a specific fragment?

Comment: How do you mean that? The String is saved in mText. It's a fragment specific field.